# close Simple Dialog in flutter when setState needs to called

Tags: flutter

I'm having a problem calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()` on my `onPressed` property in `SimpleDialogOption` widget. I need to set the state and dismiss the dialog. But calling `setState` is preventing my dialog to close. Without `setState` the dialog closes. Here is my dialog

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                          showDialog(
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return SimpleDialog(
                                  children: _children(suburbs),
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  title: Text('Pick your suburb'),
                                );
                              },
                              context: context);
                        });
```

and the method I use for the list of the Dialog:

```
List<Widget> _children(List<Suburb> suburbs) {
    return suburbs
        .map((suburb) => SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () {
              print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
              setState(() {
                postcode = suburb.name;
              });
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
            child: Text(suburb.name)))
        .toList();
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to use Navigator first and then call setState

Comment: thanks but tried that

Comment: Why don't you call `Navigator.of(context).pop()` from within the `SimpleDialogOption`, where you call the `onPressed`? The `context` within the callback might be wrong, but the one within your dialog widget should be the correct one. Unfortunately, without a concrete implementation of your dialog widget I cannot come up with anything else.

Comment: I tried that..didn't work

Answer (score 0):

you can await until the return value comes from the navigator.pop,
and then call a setState

```
     WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {

        postcode = await showDialog(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SimpleDialog(
                children: _children(suburbs),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                title: Text('Pick your suburb'),
              );
            },
            context: context);

        setState(() {
          postcode;
        });

    });



    List<Widget> _children(List<Suburb> suburbs) {
        return suburbs
            .map((suburb) => SimpleDialogOption(
            onPressed: () {
              print('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
              Navigator.of(context).pop(suburb.name);
            },
            child: Text(suburb.name)))
            .toList();
      }
```